# How do I solve this foreign constraint error in this bidirectional many to many mapping, when I try to delete a user entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have this in my BlogUser class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();`
```

And I have this in my Role class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<BlogUsers> blogUsers = new HashSet<>();`
```

Then I tried using this service to delete

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long userId){
        Optional<BlogUsers> optionalBlogUsers = blogUsersRepository.findById(userId);
        if(optionalBlogUsers.isEmpty()){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("User with Id ("+userId+"), Does not Exist ");
        }
        if(optionalBlogUsers.get().getRoles().size() > 2){
            throw new UnAuthorizedException("Not Authorized to Delete this User with id ("+userId+")");
        }
        blogUsersRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
```

And I got this error

```
2023-04-22T08:30:16.316+01:00  WARN 7381 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2023-04-22T08:30:16.316+01:00 ERROR 7381 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `FKh8ciramu9cc9q3qcqiv4ue8a6` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`))
2023-04-22T08:30:16.330+01:00 ERROR 7381 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `FKh8ciramu9cc9q3qcqiv4ue8a6` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
```